# Android Default camera capture image return image URI null

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am opening default camera app to capture image in my application but not getting captured image uri. Below is my code -

Code for open camera -

```
    initTmpUris();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Code for create image path to store -

```
private void initTmpUris() {
    File proejctDirectory = new File(CameraUtil.FOLDER_PATH + File.separator + CameraUtil.FOLDER_NAME);
    if (!proejctDirectory.exists()) {
        proejctDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    File tempDirectory = new File(proejctDirectory, "temp");
    if (!tempDirectory.exists()) {
        tempDirectory.mkdir();
    } else {
        // delete all old files
        for (File file : tempDirectory.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().startsWith("tmp_")
                    || file.getName().startsWith("croped_")) {
            }
        }

    }
    capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(tempDirectory, "tmp_"
            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

    File extraOutputFile = new File(tempDirectory, "croped_"
            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

    extraOutputFile.setWritable(true);
    cropImageUri = Uri.fromFile(extraOutputFile);
}
```

and code in onActivityResult -

```
 case REQ_CODE_PICK_FROM_CAMERA_WITHOUT_CROP: {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(null!=capturedImageUri) {
                    String imagePath = capturedImageUri.getPath();
                    File file = new File(imagePath);
                    onSingleImageSelected(reqCodeStarter, file, imagePath,
                            get_Picture_bitmap(file));
                }


            } else {
                onMediaPickCanceled(reqCodeStarter,
                        REQ_CODE_PICK_FROM_CAMERA_WITHOUT_CROP);
            }

        }
        break;
```

i am getting capturedImageUri in samsung s7 device, in other devices its return url of captured image.

Comment: check whether it has runtime permission if os use is Marshmallow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your `activity` tag inside your `Manifest` file.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

It will not let your current activity to destory and re-create so you will get the result.

Comment: My Activity is still killing and returning null